# High Read Latency in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I am using cassandra 2.1.12 on a cluster of three machines each having 32 GB of RAM and 4 core (on Amazon AWS)

I am using all default configuration of cassandra.

I am using it for my website event analysis (timeseries data) having daily  data of around 1 GB having a replcation factor of 3.

My data has grown to around 85 GB on each machine now it is giving read latency of around `4.5 s (4000 ms)`

My rows are rarely updated So, I am not using LevelOrder Compaction.
And my writes are performing well with latency of around `.03ms`

**Edited :**

Here is the definition of ColumnFamily :

```
CREATE TABLE TimeSeriesData(
logyear int,
logmonth int,
logdate int,
logdatetime timestamp,
cookie text,
sessionid text,
...
PRIMARY KEY (logyear, logmonth, logdate, logdatetime, cookie)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (logmonth ASC, logdate ASC, logdatetime ASC, cookie ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Going by my partition key which is currently logyear. So, my whole data would be in a single partition. Having said that the partitioner is responsible for distributing groups of rows (by partition key) across nodes in the cluster.

In this case would it be one a sinlge node or not?

Also, Why read latency was very poor despite of reading the data from single partition?

Can a single SSTable have multiple partition in it and vice versa?

I am using `org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner`.
Moverover, what should be the idle partition key for column family as mentioned above with a incremental data of 1GB daily.

Comment: please add consistency level and tracing dump. It might help others

Comment: I have added more details. Could you please look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're posting what you believe to be a single problem, but it's probably far more involved - potentially many different problems, all manifesting as high latency.

The most likely explanation is high garbage collection due to poor data model. However, you've given us very little to go on.

Look at `nodetool cfstats` - do the latencies in cfstats match the latencies you see? What's the maximum partition size?

Comment: if it is a problem of high garbage collection then i think my write would also have affected but they are not.

Comment: my cf stats now showing read latency of about 23481 ms
  Compacted partition minimum bytes: 43388629
  Compacted partition maximum bytes: 158683580810
  Compacted partition mean bytes: 19049359054

Comment: You have a broken data model - those partition sizes aren't reasonable, and frankly, I'm shocked you're able to read anything at all.

Comment: so how to control these partition size

Comment: You need to read about data modeling in Cassandra - you'll need to redistribute load across partitions

Comment: Having year as a partition key means that all of your data for a given year goes to RF nodes (3 nodes), but it's stored all in one logical unit (partition/row). The reason it's slow is that internally, cassandra does some nonideal things, like deserializing the index for the entire row when you read any of it - with HUGE rows, the time it takes to deserialize that index increases (and it creates JVM garbage, which causes pauses). You should limit your partitions to a few hundred megabytes (less than a million entries) unless you're using 3.6 or higher

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I would also like to know whether there is any relationship between SStables and partition like Can a single SSTable have multiple partition in it and vice versa? 
thanks in Advance

Comment: I had read about data modeling it mainly focus on two goals 
1. To keep partition size around 100mb and try to read as low partition as possible for single query.

now in my case my daily data is around 1GB so i have to partition with some other bucket to restrict the partition size and during retrieving i have to read the whole day data in one query so what data model i should apply here

Comment: The advice to keep the partition size around 100MB is far more important than the advice to retrieve as much data in one query as possible. Obey the small partition size rule, and then if necessary, you can issue multiple queries for data simultaneously / asynchronously from your application. Use the built-in fetchSize/server-side-paging to avoid reading more than necessary, and just page in data from the server as you use it.

Comment: Thanks for so much help I have changed the data model now each partition will have 100-150 MB of data. I had created a new table for upcoming data. Is there any elegant way for recovering the old data and insert it into the new table 
P.S. my table has a different structure from previous one